# Requesting user to rate/review/comment on Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way I can request user for a rating/review/comment for the application from within the application (Activity).

One option I can think is to create a link in the application to Android market where user can enter review/rating/comment. What I am looking is to allow the user to do this without leaving the application.

Also, I need to find out if the user has already reviewed. (Which case, I may choose to change the link to 'Revise the review' instead of 'Add a review').

Is this possible?

Alternatively, if I redirect to the market page, is it possible to take the user straight to the review section (not top of page)

Comment: Personally I would be tempted to give a bad review to an app bugging me to provide a rating.  I hate when apps include a "check out our other apps on the market" feature. Just my two cents.

Comment: @dbyrne well... I guess if you use the free app, it is reasonable to expect a few thanks and stars I guess. :-) The plan is not to bug the person. It is to give a menu option to write a review.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Currently the only thing you can do is direct the user to the market to rate or leave a comment. Hopefully they will build a market api in the future that will allow better app-market interaction.

Comment: Unlikely; think of the potential for abuse.

Answer (score 30):

I wrote a simple library to do that.

It is called **[AppRate](https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate)** and you can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate).

### Features:

- Do not prompt the user if the app has crashed once.
- Decide exaclty when to prompt the user. (number of launches ...)
- Customize the rate dialog to fit your application design.

### Usage example:

It is very easy to install and use:

Drop the [jar](https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate/downloads) in your `libs` folder.

Then include the following code in the `onCreate` method of your `MAIN` activity.

```
new AppRate(this)
    .setShowIfAppHasCrashed(false)
    .setMinDaysUntilPrompt(0)
    .setMinLaunchesUntilPrompt(20)
    .init();
```

- This code will show a default rate dialog after 20 launches.
- It will be shown only if the app has never crashed.
- The rate button points to your application in the Google Play Store.

I hope this can help you. :)

Comment: Must I save something in sharedPreferences?

Comment: does this check the market if the user using the app has already rated the app? i.e. what if you re-installed an already-rated app?

Comment: No unfortunately, AppRate doesn't check if the user has already rated the app. I'm not sure if this is even possible. See this question for details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284549/how-do-you-to-check-if-a-user-has-rated-your-app-on-the-android-market I hope you like it anyway. :)

Comment: ya exactly what i was thinking. it is not possible using official Android APIs due to manipulation of review. but i landed here while searching for android-market-api, which MAYBE has a feature to get rating of a particular user.

please check it out, n if possible or if it exists, try adding it to  your library. It'll be TOO cool then!

Comment: To check if user has rated before simply set a shared preference. If your app requires authentication simply return the user details with a flag on whether they have rated the app or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are several services available now in the market like : apptentive, helpshift, polljoy. Using such service can do more than just rating prompt such like user feedback and in-app survey.