# App Store / Play Store Rating completion status

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I am having one specific requirement as "Displaying one notification to provide rating of the app when application is launched". If rating is already completed, this popup should not be displayed. Is there any option available to identify this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't anyway to tell if the user has actually rated the app. The best way I've found is to just display the dialog at some given time (for me it was after the app was launched 5 times) to ask them if they either like the application or have feedback to provide. If they like the application then you take them to the store page to leave a rating, if they have feedback you open an email intent so they can email you what issues they have. Also provide a way for them to never ask again or to remind them later, if they are to be reminded later then you can save that as a `SharedPreference` to remind them after x app launches or after a certain date in the future.

Comment: Not really, if a user selects to rate your application, you can internally store a value identifying that the user has "rated" the app and you can use it to never ask for ratings again. Those that use SQLite as internal DB can create a column field to store that value.

Comment: It is not right way to store the value only based on redirection to store to provide rating. Because If user doesn't provide rating even after redirection to appStore/playStore and return to application, that user is still not provided rating.. So for that user, we are not able to display notification to rate afterwards..

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284549/how-do-you-to-check-if-a-user-has-rated-your-app-on-the-android-market