# From an Android app, is it possible to query the number of stars current user has rated the app with?

Tags: android

From an Android app, is it possible to programmatically get the number of stars current user has given to the app ?

Is there an extension or API to query this info ?

I need this to:

- Invite user to rate the app only if he hasn't done it yet.
- Invite user to rate again the app if he has given 1 or 2 stars on an old version of the app.

Comment: This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284549/how-do-you-to-check-if-a-user-has-rated-your-app-on-the-google-play

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you to check if a user has rated your app on the Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284549/how-do-you-to-check-if-a-user-has-rated-your-app-on-the-google-play)