# Is it possible to check if user already given rating to your app?

Tags: android, google-play, rating

As per my requirement, rating popup will appear to user for app rating and redirects to play store. If the user already given rating to app then the popup will not shown. I want to get app ratings programmatically. Google provide Reply to Reviews API but that will only returned the reviews with comments. But I need both rating and reviews. I have searched for this but don't get anything relevant.

Can anyone please explain how can I do this ?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Google blocks it to prevent rewarding ratings.

Best you can do is intercept the click, then disable the popup even if the user just visited your store page without rating.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11284580/8609783